# Show when $x\neq y$ then in a Metric space $d(x,y):= \epsilon > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance

Let $X$ be a Metric space and $x\neq y$. Show that $d(x,y):= \epsilon > 0$ and I am given as a hint to show that that $B_{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x)\cap B_{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}}(y)=\varnothing$

My idea:

Assume that $B_{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x)\cap B_{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}}(y)\neq\varnothing \Rightarrow z \in B_{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x)\cap B_{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}}(y)\Rightarrow \epsilon :=d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)<\epsilon$ which is a contradiction. Thus $B_{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x)\cap B_{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}}(y)=\varnothing$

I have shown the hint, but how does this prove that $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: What is the function $d$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I think it would be the measure of distance between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Which distance? All we have here is a Hausdorff space. Why should it be metrizable?

Comment: My guess is that you are to show that every metric space is Hausdorff ... If $d$ is a metric, then *by definition* we have $d(x,y)>0$ for $x\ne y$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos apologies, $X$ is a metric space

Comment: Well, then $d(x,y)>0$ follows simply by definition of a metric. You don't even need to know what is a Hausdorff space for that.

Comment: If $X$ is a metric space, then you are nearly done.  By definition of Hausdorff, for any two distinct points $x,y$, we can find disjoint neighborhoods ($\epsilon>0$) $B_x(\epsilon/2),B_y(\epsilon/2)$ with $B_x,B_y$ disjoint.  The distance between $x$ and $y$ is $\epsilon$.

Comment: You are  $defining$  $\epsilon$ as $d(x,y)$ and part of the definition of a metric is that if $x\ne y$ then $d(x,y)>0.$ If this condition is erased from the definition of a metric then what remains is called the definition of a pseudo-metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **definition** of a metric, there is the clause (Or a variation of it):

$$\forall x,y \in X: d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y\tag{1}$$

Plus the fact that $d$ is defined a function from $X \times X \to \mathbb{R}^+$ (So that all values are $\ge 0$ implicitly) or as an a function to $\mathbb{R}$ with an extra explicit

$$\forall x,y \in X: d(x,y) \ge 0\tag{2}$$

The combination of these facts gives that if $x \neq y$, then $d(x,y) \ge 0$ by (2), or its implicit version, but $d(x,y)=0$ is ruled out (1), as $d(x,y)=0$ would imply $x=y$ while we know that $x \neq y$. And if a real number is $\ge 0$ but not $0$ by definition it's $>0$.